# Glassfish Closing JDBC Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I am new to **Glassfish** and **Java EE**, and I try to develop a project using *glassfish as the server*. The problem I have is that sometiems glassfish takes too long to deploy the project because **it is closing JDBC Connections**, and that takes too long.

```
SEVERE:   Closing JDBC Connection 0
SEVERE:   Closing JDBC Connection 1
SEVERE:   Closing JDBC Connection 2
SEVERE:   Closing JDBC Connection 3
SEVERE:   Closing JDBC Connection 4
...........
SEVERE:   Closing JDBC Connection 19
```

I don't know if the problem is from the glassfish server or from my code.. I am closing the connections after using them..

Can you please help me with figuring out where the problem comes from and how can I solve it?

I will add some more info.

I am using **GlassFish Server 4.1** and **Java EE 7** Web.

For connections, I have the following classes:

```
public class PooledConnection {


private Connection connection = null;
private boolean inuse = false;

// Constructor that takes the passed in JDBC Connection
// and stores it in the connection attribute.
public PooledConnection(Connection value) {
    if (value != null) {
        this.connection = value;
    }
}

// Returns a reference to the JDBC Connection
public Connection getConnection() {
    // get the JDBC Connection
    return this.connection;
}

// Set the status of the PooledConnection.
public void setInUse(boolean value) {
    inuse = value;
}

//Returns the current status of the PooledConnection.
public boolean inUse() {
    return inuse;
}

// Close the real JDBC Connection
public void close() {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println(sqle.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The ConnectionPool class

```
public class ConnectionPool {

// JDBC Driver Name
private String driver = null;
// URL of database
private String url = null;
// Initial number of connections.
private int size = 0;
// Username
private String username = null;
// Password
private String password = null;
// Vector of JDBC Connections
private ArrayList<PooledConnection> pool = null;
private ArrayList<PooledConnection> poolInUse = null;
private ArrayList<PooledConnection> poolNotInUse  = null;


public ConnectionPool() {
}

// Set the value of the JDBC Driver
public void setDriver(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        driver = value;
    }
}

// Get the value of the JDBC Driver
public String getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

// Set the URL Pointing to the Datasource
public void setURL(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        url = value;
    }
}

// Get the URL Pointing to the Datasource
public String getURL() {
    return url;
}

// Set the initial number of connections
public void setSize(int value) {
    if (value > 1) {
        size = value;
    }
}

// Get the initial number of connections
public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

// Set the username
public void setUsername(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        username = value;
    }
}

// Get the username
public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}

// Set the password
public void setPassword(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        password = value;
    }
}

// Get the password
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

// Creates and returns a connection
private Connection createConnection() throws Exception {
    Connection con = null;
    // Create a Connection
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return con;
}

// Initialize the pool
public synchronized void initializePool() throws Exception {
    // Check our initial values
    if (driver == null) {
        throw new Exception("No Driver Name Specified!");
    }
    if (url == null) {
        throw new Exception("No URL Specified!");
    }
    if (size < 1) {
        throw new Exception("Pool size is less than 1!");
    }
    // Create the Connections
    try {
        // Load the Driver class file

        Class.forName(driver);
        // Create Connections based on the size member
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            System.err.println("Opening JDBC Connection " + x);
            Connection con = createConnection();
            if (con != null) {
                // Create a PooledConnection to encapsulate the real JDBC Connection
                PooledConnection pcon = new PooledConnection(con);
                // Add the Connection to the pool
                addConnection(pcon);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println(sqle.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println(cnfe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Adds the PooledConnection to the pool
private void addConnection(PooledConnection value) {
    // If the pool is null, create a new vector with the initial size of 
    if(pool == null)
    {
        pool = new ArrayList<PooledConnection>(size);
    }

    pool.add(value);
}

public synchronized void releaseConnection(Connection con)
{
    if(con != null)  
    {
        // find the PooledConnection Object
        for (int x = 0; x < pool.size(); x++) {
            PooledConnection pcon = pool.get(x);
            // Check for correct Connection
            if (pcon.getConnection() == con) {
                System.err.println("Releasing Connection " + x);
                // Set its inuse attribute to false, which
                // releases it for use
                pcon.setInUse(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Find an available connection
public synchronized Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    PooledConnection pcon = null;
    // find a connection not in use
    for (int x = 0; x < pool.size(); x++) {
        pcon = pool.get(x);
        // Check to see if the Connection is in use
        if (pcon.inUse() == false) {
            // Mark it as in use
            pcon.setInUse(true);
            // return the JDBC Connection stored in the
            // PooledConnection object
            return pcon.getConnection();
        }
    }
    // Could not find a free connection, create and add a new one
    try {
        // Create a new JDBC Connection
        Connection con = createConnection();
        // Create a new PooledConnection, passing it the JDBC Connection
        pcon = new PooledConnection(con);
        // Mark the connection as in use
        pcon.setInUse(true);
        // Add the new PooledConnection object to the pool
        pool.add(pcon);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    // return the new Connection
    return pcon.getConnection();
}

// When shutting down the pool, you need to first empty it.
public synchronized void emptyPool() {
    // Iterate over the entire pool closing the JDBC Connections.
    for (int x = 0; x < pool.size(); x++) {
        System.err.println("Closing JDBC Connection " + x);
        PooledConnection pcon = pool.get(x);
        // If the PooledConnection is not in use, close it
        if (pcon.inUse() == false) {
            pcon.close();
        } else {
            // If it is still in use, sleep for 30 seconds and force close.
            try {
                java.lang.Thread.sleep(30000);
                pcon.close();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.err.println(ie.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the DBAccessController

```
public final class DBAccessController {

private Connection connection = null;

public DBAccessController(String url, String userId, String password, boolean typereadonly) {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userId, password);
        connection.setReadOnly(typereadonly);
    } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exceptionClassNotFound) {
    } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException instantException) {
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalAccessException illegalAccess) {
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException sqle) {
    }

}

public DBAccessController(Connection con) {

    if (con != null) {
        this.connection = con;
    }

}


public final synchronized ArrayList runSQL(String queryString, List<String> parametrii) {
    try {

        PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < parametrii.size(); i++) {
            prepStmt.setString((i + 1), parametrii.get(i));
        }
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

        boolean flag = prepStmt.execute();


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rezultate = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet keyset = prepStmt.getGeneratedKeys();

        while (keyset != null && keyset.next()) {

            HashMap<String, String> keysHM = new HashMap<>();
            // Retrieve the auto generated key(s).
            int key = keyset.getInt(1);
            keysHM.put("cheia", Integer.toString(key));
            rezultate.add(keysHM);

        }

        if (flag) {
            ResultSet res = prepStmt.getResultSet();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            while (res.next()) {

                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

                    Object o = res.getObject(i);

                    if (o != null) {
                        hm.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), o.toString());
                    }
                }

                rezultate.add(hm);
            }

            res.close();
            prepStmt.close();
            return rezultate;

        } else {
            prepStmt.close();
            if (keyset != null) {
                return rezultate;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException sqle) {
        return null;
    }
}



public final synchronized ArrayList runSQL(String queryString) {
    try {

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        boolean flag = statement.execute();

        System.out.println("Statement: " + statement + " flag: " + flag);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rezultate = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet keyset = statement.getGeneratedKeys();

        while (keyset != null && keyset.next()) {

            HashMap<String, String> keysHM = new HashMap<>();
            // Retrieve the auto generated key(s).
            int key = keyset.getInt(1);
            keysHM.put("cheia", Integer.toString(key));
            rezultate.add(keysHM);

            System.out.println("Cheile " + keyset.toString());

        }

        System.out.println("Cheile " + keyset.toString());
        if (flag) {
            ResultSet res = statement.getResultSet();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = res.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            System.out.println("res: " + res + " rsmd: " + rsmd + " numberOfColumns: " + numberOfColumns);

            while (res.next()) {

                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                System.out.println("Res to string " + res.toString());
                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                    System.out.println("obiectul " + i + " res.getObject(i) " + res.getObject(i));

                    Object o = res.getObject(i);
                    System.out.println("rsmd.getColumnName(i) " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));

                    if (o != null) {
                        hm.put(rsmd.getColumnName(i), o.toString());
                    }
                }

                rezultate.add(hm);
            }

            res.close();
            statement.close();
            System.out.println("Return rezultate");
            return rezultate;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Return null 1");
            statement.close();
            if (keyset != null) {
                return rezultate;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

    } catch (java.sql.SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Return null 2" + sqle.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public final void stop() {

    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
    }
}

}
```

When I need to use a connection I do the following (for example):

```
Connection con;
                try {
                    con = cp.getConnection();
                    udao = new UtilizatorDAO(con);
                    con.close();
                    }


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(RegisterController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                out.close();
```

Comment: It would be a pleasure to help you, but you've given absolutly no informations about your problem. Edit your post by giving the version of Glassfish and Java you are using, code sections of the important parts, etc.

Comment: I added some more details. I hope this can help :)

Comment: Why did you implement connection pooling on your own? It is already integrated in Glassfish.